# Python: Reduce() and function as argument of function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

In Python3 I am Trying to figure out about reduce() and function as argument of function, or better passing a function as an argument of another one where the first one is not explicit see below

given:

```
# define a function `call` where you provide the function and the arguments
def call(y,f):
    return f(y)

# define a function that returns the square
square = lambda x : x*x

# define a function that returns the increment
increment = lambda x : x+1

# define a function that returns the cube
cube = lambda x : x*x*x

# define a function that returns the decrement
decrement = lambda x : x-1

# put all the functions in a list in the order that you want to execute them
funcs = [square, increment, cube, decrement]

#bring it all together. Below is the non functional part. 
#in functional programming you separate the functional and the non functional parts.
from functools import reduce # reduce is in the functools library
print(reduce(call, funcs,1)) # output 7 , 2  res 124
```

why it doesnt work if

I change

```
def call(y,f)
       f(y)
```

in

```
def call(f,y)
       f(y)
```

and gives out a  error:

```
................py", line 27, in call
    return f(y)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does it work with `def call(f,y):f(y)`?, 
The way reduce is called, in your function `call` your first argument should be the function and second should be the int.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: Why the expected output is `7 , 2  res 124`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## functools.reduce()

To understand this, we should first understand how `reduce` works, reduce takes 3 arguments:

- A function
- An iterable element
- An initializer.

Let us focus on the function and iterable element to understand how function is called

Below is the official docs of functools:

> `functools.reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])`
>
> Apply function of 
>   two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to
>   right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value. For example,
>   reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
>   ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5). The left argument, x, is the accumulated value and
>   the right argument, y, is the update value from the iterable. If the
>   optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the
>   iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the iterable
>   is empty. If initializer is not given and iterable contains only one
>   item, the first item is returned.
>
> Roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
>     it = iter(iterable)
>     if initializer is None:
>         value = next(it)
>     else:
>         value = initializer
>     for element in it:
>         value = function(value, element)
>     return value
> ```

Here you could understand that, it takes the function passed in the first argument and executes it with value, element as arguments for the function passed. Note that element is each `element` in the second argument `iterable`. So when you called `reduce(call, funcs, 1)`,

The following happened:
Since initializer=1, value=initializer,

for every func in funcs, the following happened

call(1,func)

TLDR;
**When you replace y and f, you are trying to call 1(func) which is not possible and that is why the first initial solution works because it calls func(1)**

Reference: [Python Docs - functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce)

Comment: thanks Udaya. Still confused to me but kind of got it. In my case with initializer = 1 then in call y=1 so f(1) makes sense while swapping y and ,1(f) it's not possible ?

Comment: Exactly. That resonates with the error `'int' object is not callable` you get.

Comment: Also, if you do not pass any initializer, remember that it will take the first element of the iterable as the `value` for calling the function first time

Comment: If you feel this answer satisfies, kindly make sure you mark it as the right one :)